# Custom launcher

Tags: android, launcher

I have developed two Android launcher and wanted to know if you can set the default launcher programatically. In practice I do not want to appear in the dialog's initial choice of launcher on the device.

Comment: I need your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339932/set-google-as-search-bar-in-home-screen-custom-launcher-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

This is possible only for System apps. So unless you have root access, I dont think this is possible

Comment: I need your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339932/set-google-as-search-bar-in-home-screen-custom-launcher-programmatically