# Set google as search bar in home screen Custom launcher programmatically

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher, android-qsb

I am creating 'my own launcher`. In that case I want to put`Quick search bar` in my home screen i.e. Google now launcher.

How can I do that. I have gone through multiple threads but not found any relevant answer.

I don't want to show the `widget picker`.I want asap user install this launcher search bar should be there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1169390 can you please help me on this?

Comment: have you found any workaround for this problem? I am at the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search bar is not displayed because the launcher doesn't have permissions to show the widget.

As you probably already figured out, if a user explicitly adds the search bar widget to any screen, he will be prompted to give the permission, and the search bar on top also appears.

The problem is that `getOrCreateQsbBar` method in `Launcher` class (I assume you forked Launcher3) doesn't ask for permissions if it can't instantiate the widget, it instead silently fails. The problem is in this snippet inside of `getOrCreateQsbBar`:

```
    if (!AppWidgetManagerCompat.getInstance(this)
            .bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(widgetId, searchProvider, opts)) {
        mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(widgetId);
        widgetId = -1;
    }
```

Instead of just resetting `widgetId` to `-1` you want to ask for permissions to install the widget and call `getOrCreateQsbBar` again. Here's an example code that asks for permission:

```
    boolean hasPermission = appWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(widgetId, searchProvider);
    if (!hasPermission)
    {
        mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(widgetId);
        widgetId = -1;

        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PROVIDER, searchProvider);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BIND);
    }
```

Then overload `onActivityResult` in the `Launcher` class, something along the lines of:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_BIND) {
        mSearchDropTargetBar.setQsbSearchBar(getOrCreateQsbBar());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend you to clone Launcher3 repository from AOSP.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/

If you checkout nougat-mr5 branch you can look at the code to show searchbar by taking the component from GMS package and including it as a row element. Please look for QSB in the code.